# Using paypal SDK and custom configuration not from web.config

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I'm trying to use Paypal .net sdk with dynamic configuration (not from web config). I found overload for PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService class, which can be initiated with Dictionary object, which actually represents configuration. Topic on github https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/issues/1 . My code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> paypalConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
paypalConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
paypalConfig.Add("connectionTimeout", "30000");
paypalConfig.Add("requestRetries", "5");
paypalConfig.Add("IPAddress", "127.0.0.1");
paypalConfig.Add("apiUsername", "***.gmail.com");
paypalConfig.Add("apiPassword", "api password goes here");
paypalConfig.Add("apiSignature", "signature goes here");
paypalConfig.Add("applicationId", "sandbox app id");
paypalConfig.Add("signatureSubject", "");
paypalConfig.Add("certificateSubject", "");


PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(paypalConfig);

DoDirectPaymentResponseType response = service.DoDirectPayment(wrapper);
```

When i call DoDirectPayment(wrapper) method i get MissingCredentialException with message "Missing credentials for ". And now the question: How to properly initialize custom configuration? What keys should i use? I couldn't find any information for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PayPal documentation infuriates me sometimes. They say 'check out the samples' and then there isn't a single sample that references this constructor!

Fortunately they did explain it [on this page](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/PayPalMerchantSDK).

> ...Or, by dynamically passing in a dictionary (that you can load from
>   a database or as suits your needs).

```
Dictionary<string, string> config = new Dictionary<string, string>();
config.Add("mode", "sandbox");
config.Add("account1.apiUsername", "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com");
config.Add("account1.apiPassword", "...");
config.Add("account1.apiSignature", "...");

PayPalAPIInterfaceService s = new  PayPalAPIInterfaceService(config);
```

Comment: i realize this is the same answer as @cmd but I wanted to post the official list of things required. applicationId here doesn't seem to be required for basic operation - but it's possible that it is if you are using advanced APIs that need approval

Answer (score 1):

That's funny, but i found the solution right after i posted this question :)
So, proper way to init custom configuration:

```
Dictionary<string, string> paypalConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
paypalConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
paypalConfig.Add("connectionTimeout", "30000");
paypalConfig.Add("requestRetries", "5");
paypalConfig.Add("IPAddress", "127.0.0.1");
paypalConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", "***.gmail.com");
paypalConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", "*******");
paypalConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", "api signature here");
paypalConfig.Add("account1.applicationId", "app id here");
paypalConfig.Add("account1.signatureSubject", "");
paypalConfig.Add("account1.certificateSubject", "");
```

So i just had to add "account1" prefix before configuration property.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your account credentials.change in the following areas.

```
aypalConfig.Add("apiUsername", "***.gmail.com");
paypalConfig.Add("apiPassword", "api password goes here");
paypalConfig.Add("apiSignature", "signature goes here");
paypalConfig.Add("applicationId", "sandbox app id");
```

Go to your account for developer.Here you will get the required information.

Comment: Hi Ehsan, thanks for reply but i already know my account credentials. I replaced them just before posting example of code. See my own answer.

Comment: Thats good ,You get your solution.Well Done.If my answer helps you or may help others.Please approve it.Thanks.@cmd

Answer (score 0):

You can override Paypal test credential by you test account
Paypal APIContext class have dictionary Config where you can specify credentials as follow

```
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(GetAccessToken());
apiContext.Config = GetConfig();

private static Dictionary<string, string> GetConfig()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> configMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    configMap.Add("mode", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mode"].ToString());
    configMap.Add("account0.apiUsername",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUsername"].ToString());
    configMap.Add("account0.apiPassword", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiPassword"].ToString());
    configMap.Add("account0.apiSignature", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiSignature"].ToString());
    configMap.Add("account0.apiCertificate", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiCertificate"].ToString());
    configMap.Add("account0.privateKeyPassword", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["privateKeyPassword"].ToString());
    configMap.Add("account0.subject", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["subject"].ToString());   configMap.Add("account0.applicationId",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationId"].ToString());

    return configMap;
}
```

I am storing my keys in web config you can add them directly

I got another way to do same from web Config file

```
<configSections>
<section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPalCoreSDK"/>
</configSections>

<!-- PayPal SDK config -->
<paypal>
<settings>
  <add name="endpoint" value="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com"/>
  <add name="connectionTimeout" value="360000"/>
  <add name="requestRetries" value="1"/>
  <add name="ClientID" value="AUSaZxBqv5PQ2eQ2XyNfhgo2- q_sf7WOKxoOgvbjP_y_KOy0fbKUYApiEZJE"/>
  <add name="ClientSecret" value="EBDXUBA040ErNqIfDpvh1KZqSaRJhANQuQWl-OHtsSrhEa93o3GICa7WoyF-"/>
</settings>
<accounts>
  <account apiUsername="rhealb_1340347945_biz_api1.gmail.com" apiPassword="1340347981" apiSignature="ATm0VCcoUsJbzRddp810M7zr08G.AAZF2y729RqpgeeyThP.1mI1qXYT"/>
</accounts>
```

Setting Section is Optional.
I am using SDK first time so i really don't know where clientId and ClientSecret get used